# What is `lr_policy` in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I just try to find out how I can use [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/). To do so, I just took a look at the different `.prototxt` files in the examples folder. There is one option I don't understand:

```
# The learning rate policy
lr_policy: "inv"
```

Possible values seem to be:

- `"fixed"`
- `"inv"`
- `"step"`
- `"multistep"`
- `"stepearly"`
- `"poly"`

Could somebody please explain those options?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you look inside the `/caffe-master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto` file (you can find it online [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L157-L172)) you will see the following descriptions:

```
// The learning rate decay policy. The currently implemented learning rate
// policies are as follows:
//    - fixed: always return base_lr.
//    - step: return base_lr * gamma ^ (floor(iter / step))
//    - exp: return base_lr * gamma ^ iter
//    - inv: return base_lr * (1 + gamma * iter) ^ (- power)
//    - multistep: similar to step but it allows non uniform steps defined by
//      stepvalue
//    - poly: the effective learning rate follows a polynomial decay, to be
//      zero by the max_iter. return base_lr (1 - iter/max_iter) ^ (power)
//    - sigmoid: the effective learning rate follows a sigmod decay
//      return base_lr ( 1/(1 + exp(-gamma * (iter - stepsize))))
//
// where base_lr, max_iter, gamma, step, stepvalue and power are defined
// in the solver parameter protocol buffer, and iter is the current iteration.
```

Answer (score 54):

It is a common practice to decrease the learning rate (lr) as the optimization/learning process progresses. However, it is not clear how exactly the learning rate should be decreased as a function of the iteration number.

If you use [DIGITS](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS) as an interface to Caffe, you will be able to visually see how the different choices affect the learning rate.

**fixed:** the learning rate is kept fixed throughout the learning process.

---

**inv:** the learning rate is decaying as ~`1/T`
[image]

---

**step:** the learning rate is piecewise constant, dropping every X iterations
[image]

---

**multistep:** piecewise constant at arbitrary intervals
[image]

---

You can see exactly how the learning rate is computed in the function [`SGDSolver<Dtype>::GetLearningRate`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp#L27) (*solvers/sgd_solver.cpp* line ~30).

---

Recently, I came across an interesting and unconventional approach to learning-rate tuning: [Leslie N. Smith's work "No More Pesky Learning Rate Guessing Games"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01186). In his report, Leslie suggests to use `lr_policy` that alternates between decreasing and *increasing* the learning rate. His work also suggests how to implement this policy in Caffe.

Comment: No More Pesky ... is apparently similar in performance to using adadelta. There are now multiple adaptive schemes available in Caffe.