# deep learning - a number of naive questions about caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to understand the basics of caffe, in particular to use with python.

My understanding is that the model definition (say a given neural net architecture) must be included in the `'.prototxt'` file.

And that when you train the model on data using the `'.prototxt'`, you save the weights/model parameters to a `'.caffemodel'` file

Also, there is a difference between the `'.prototxt'` file used for training (which includes learning rate and regularization parameters) and the one used for testing/deployment, which does not include them.

**Questions:**

1. is it correct that the `'.prototxt'` is the basis for training and that
   the `'.caffemodel'` is the result of training (weights), using the
   `'.prototxt'` on the training data?
2. is it correct that there is a `'.prototxt'` for training and one for
   testing, and that there are only slight differences (learning rate
   and regularization factors on training), but that the nn
   architecture (assuming you use neural nets) is the same?

Apologies for such basic questions and possibly some very incorrect assumptions, I am doing some online research and the lines above summarize my understanding to date.

Comment: Please limit yourself to **one question** per post. This is too broad.

Comment: Hi Matt, I understand. I removed question 3, which is the broadest one. I left two questions, but they are highly interrelated yes/no questions - hope this is ok.

Comment: For your other question regarding "solving" using python interface, you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32509003/1714410) relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shai, great tip.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's take a look at one of the examples provided with BVLC/caffe: [`bvlc_reference_caffenet`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet).
You'll notice that in fact there are **3** `'.prototxt'` files:

- [`train_val.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt): this file describe the net architecture for the training phase.
- [`depoly.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt): this file describe the net architecture for test time ("deployment").
- [`solver.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/solver.prototxt): this file is very small and contains "meta parameters" for training. For example, the [learning rate policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033096/what-is-lr-policy-in-caffe/30045244#30045244), [regulariztion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177764/what-is-weight-decay-meta-parameter-in-caffe) etc.

The net architecture represented by `train_val.prototxt` and `deploy.prototxt` should be mostly similar. There are few main difference between the two:

- Input data: during training one usually use a predefined set of inputs for training/validation. Therefore, `train_val` usually contains an explicit input layer, e.g., `"HDF5Data"` layer or a `"Data"` layer. On the other hand, `deploy` usually does not know in advance what inputs it will get, it only contains a statement:

  ```
  input: "data"
  input_shape {
    dim: 10
    dim: 3
    dim: 227
    dim: 227
  }
  ```

  that declares what input the net expects and what should be its dimensions.
  Alternatively, One can put an [`"Input"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/input.html) layer:

  ```
  layer {
    name: "input"
    type: "Input"
    top: "data"
    input_param { shape { dim: 10 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } }
  }
  ```
- Input labels: during training we supply the net with the "ground truth" expected outputs, this information is obviously not available during `deploy`.
- Loss layers: during training one must define a loss layer. This layer tells the solver in what direction it should tune the parameters at each iteration. This loss compares the net's current prediction to the expected "ground truth". The gradient of the loss is back-propagated to the rest of the net and this is what drives the learning process. During `deploy` there is no loss and no back-propagation.

In caffe, you supply a `train_val.prototxt` describing the net, the train/val datasets and the loss. In addition, you supply a `solver.prototxt` describing the meta parameters for training. The *output* of the training process is a `.caffemodel` binary file containing the trained parameters of the net.
Once the net was trained, you can use the `deploy.prototxt` with the `.caffemodel` parameters to predict outputs for new and unseen inputs.

Comment: thanks a ,lot Shai. This is an awesome response. Could have not asked for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but, there is diffrent types of  .prototxt files
for example

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt

this is for the training and testing network

for commandline training ypu can use a solver file which is also  .prototxt file for example

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt