# What parts an parameters of train_val.prototxt, solver.prototxt, and deploy.prototxt should be changed based on our own data?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, deeplearning4j, matcaffe

I am confused about changing the parameters for training a `net` in caffe based on our own data.

- Which layers of net we should pay attention more to train the net on
  our own data? For example, the number of outputs based on the number
  of classes.

I tried to train FCN32 for semantic segmentation. I changed the number of outputs in `Deconvolution layer (i.e.,upscore_sign)` to the number of classes in my data, but it is giving an error.

- We have different outputs in different convolutional layers. How can
  I detect different outputs from each other and which one should I
  change?
- The next question is what is the difference between `deploy.prototxt`
  and `train_val.prototxt`.
- And what is the application of deploy.prototxt? Should I change the
  layers in `deploy.prototxt` based on the train_val.prototxt?

I really appreciate if someone knows, please share your knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which layer of the net we should pay attention

When finetuning a model to a new task, with probably different number of labels, one **must** change `num_output` of the last layer.
The last layer serves as a probability prediction layer, outputting a vector of probabilities for each predicted variable: For image classification, the net predicts a prob vector per image; In FCN the net outputs prob vector *pre pixel*. The prob vector is of length = number of labels = `num_output` of last layer. Thus you must change this value to accommodate for the new number of labels in your new task.
See [this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36842553/1714410).

> What is the difference between `'deploy.prototxt'` and `'train_val.prototxt'`

This difference is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973370/1714410).

> Should I change the layers in `'deploy.prototxt'` based on the `'train_val.prototxt'`?

Yes!

Comment: Thank you very much :) I am your big fan.....Always helping us here... thanks again